# Using AJAX to change content - when users navigate to direct URL new content is not displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to create a page that refreshes content within a div async alongside providing a user with an anchor to enable direct access to the content within the div. (e.g. www.website.co.uk/#page1)

I've managed to make it so that the content can be updated for 1 page, however, if I add multiple pages it stops working

Additionally - if I was to navigate to the URL website.co.uk/#page1 it wont display #page1.

Can anyone help?

This is my current code:

**HTML :**

```
<h5> <a href="#page1">Test</a></h5>
<h5> <a href="#page2">Test2</a></h5>
```

**JS :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var routes = {
        '#page1' : '{{site.url}}/page1'
        '#page2' : '{{site.url}}/page2'
    };
    var routeHandler = function( event ) {
        var hash = window.location.hash, 
            xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
            }
        };
        xhttp.open("GET", routes[hash], true);
        xhttp.send();    
    };
    window.addEventListener('hashchange', routeHandler);
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        var hash = window.location.hash;
        if (routes.hasOwnProperty(hash)) routehandler();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you upload jsfiddle?

Comment: I've added it - however, because multiple documents are used i dont think it'd be fruitful ... https://jsfiddle.net/s6dastka/1/